# How to access files using jQuery's get function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load files that the user selects in a multiselect element. A minimal example would be something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="file-select" id="file-select" multiple>
            <option>http://url.to.file/Test1.txt</option>
            <option>http://url.to.file/Test2.txt</option>
        </select>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#file-select').change(function () {
                    let loaded_files_list = new Array();
                    let promise = new Promise(function(myResolve,myReject) {
                        $("#file-select option:selected").each(function () {
                            $.get($(this).val(), function(response) {
                                data = response;
                                // Do something with data
                                loaded_files_list.push($(this).val());
                                if(loaded_files_list.length == $("#file-select option:selected").length) {
                                    myResolve(loaded_files_list);
                                }
                                else {
                                    myReject('List is not complete yet');
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }); 
                    promise.then(
                        function(value) {
                            console.log(value);
                        },
                        function(error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    );  
                }); 
            });


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

where the files `Test1.txt` and `Test2.txt` are hosted by the same server as the web page. If I use this set-up I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
at S.fn.init.val (jquery.min.js:2:69494)
at Object.success (ajax_test.html:21:40)
at c (jquery.min.js:2:28327)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:29072)
at l (jquery.min.js:2:79901)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:82355)
```

I don't understand where that error is coming from. Where is jQuery using .toLowerCase where it does not seem to be defined?

Comment: The error doesn't appear to be coming from the code in your question.

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan this is all the code that I am executing unfortunately.

Comment: there is a bug in your code.  `loaded_files_list.push($(this).val());` <-- I think you mean the select box value with this code, but it's within a callback, so the "this" has changed. you can work around this by adding a `var $this=$(this)` before you call `$.get()`, then change that line to `loaded_files_list.push($this.val())`